# Universal Linking not working with other app webview

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-deep-linking

Universal Linking is not working from other apps like gmail. If I click on reply to which is hyperlinked to my website from gmail app it is opening in webview while when I open it from browser gmail it successfully redirects to my app.

AppDelegate Changes:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
  restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
  {
    return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                    continueUserActivity:userActivity
                      restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  }
```

Also added these app links

```
<array>
    <string>applinks:seller.hireanartist.com.au</string>
</array>
```

The apple-site-association file is also uploaded properly.